# Modifying a For Loop in R to Work with Spreadsheet

Tags: r

I have a for loop that adds up every value in a spreadsheet along rows and prints the totals. I need to modify it to add up columns instead, find the average value among each column, and print the label for the column.
Here's the for loop I have:

```
for(i in 1:14){
 sumALL [i] = sum(basalts[i,-1])
 print(sumALL [i])

}
```

Here is the spreadsheet

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do

```
colSums(basalts[, -1])
```

Same works with `colMeans` If you want the average.

---

Solution with for loop:

```
sum_all <- numeric()

for (i in 2:ncol(basalts))
{
  sum_all[i-1] <- sum(basalts[, i])
}
```

Comment: You're a genius. Thanks! If I did want to do this with a for loop, what would that look like?

Comment: See my updated answer. However, I don‘t see any good reason to use a for loop here except maybe for some exercise/practicing reasons. E.g. the colSums solution also gives you the corresponding column name, whereas the simple for loop in my solution does not. colSums is also considerably faster than the for loop (I think).

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it so that others can benefit  from it.

Comment: Excellent. This is for a geochemistry lab so we were asked to use for loop just as an exercise. I upvoted but it says I don't have enough reputation for it to count. Sorry about that, I'm new here and not a dev.

Comment: That‘s fine. You can still click on the checkmark, though, to mark it as the accepted answer.